# Compare two date columns that has texts on it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this,

```
datecol1              datecol2
2005-02-22          EmployeeNotFound
2010-02-21          2010-02-22
EmployeeNotFound    EmployeeNotFound
EmployeeNotFound    2010-02-22
```

Both the columns have a dtype of Object.

I want to compare these two columns and get the maximum date on it for each column.

So the expected result is

```
    datecol1            datecol2                  ExpectedResult
    2005-02-22          EmployeeNotFound          2005-02-22
    2010-02-21          2010-02-22                2010-02-22
    EmployeeNotFound    EmployeeNotFound          EmployeeNotFound
    EmployeeNotFound    2010-02-25                2010-02-25
```

The dtype of ExpectedResult will again be an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert columns to datetimes, get `max` per axis 1 and last convert to string and replace `NaT`s:

```
cols = ['datecol1', 'datecol2']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
df['ExpectedResult'] = df[cols].max(axis=1)
df = df.astype(str).replace('NaT','EmployeeNotFound')
#alternative solution
#df = df.astype(str).mask(df.isnull(),'EmployeeNotFound')
print (df)
           datecol1          datecol2    ExpectedResult
0        2005-02-22  EmployeeNotFound        2005-02-22
1        2010-02-21        2010-02-22        2010-02-22
2  EmployeeNotFound  EmployeeNotFound  EmployeeNotFound
3  EmployeeNotFound        2010-02-22        2010-02-22
```

Comment: I think my method is wrong . You are right ! :-) just a little bit improvement `df[['datecol1', 'datecol2']].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy as numpy functions are faster.

```
import numpy as np
cond = df['datecol1'] != 'EmployeeNotFound'
df['ExpectedResult'] = np.where(cond, df['datecol1'], df['datecol2'])
```

Here first all the valid values of `datecol1` will be filled and then remaining will be filled by the second column `datecol2`.